# Closed basis for product topology

Tags: general-topology, product-space

Is there some good basis or subbasis of closed sets for the product topology? I was thinking about something simpler than just the complements of the usual open basis.

Comment: Sets of the form $\prod_\alpha C_\alpha$, where each $C_\alpha$ is closed and at most one is not $X_\alpha$, are a simple subbase for the closed sets, but the base that they generate is just the complements of the sets in the usual open base. I don’t know of anything nicer.

Comment: Thank you. It helps but I need a really simpler form. Probably it does not exist.